# Extract moving object from video taken by moving camera(drone) using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project where i have to detect moving object from moving camera for example: detecting hanging apples on trees using drone, detecting animals in farm using drone and detecting flowers on field like this. the main thing is i am using moving camera and i don't have fixed lighting condition as the video is captured in outdoor so i lighting may vary. I have to use open CV and python please suggest me reliable method that can be used for example as mentioned above.I know some basic method like background subtraction and motion detection but as my lighting conditions are not stationary i am not getting proper output

Answer (score 0):

You can try optical flow. Since your platform is moving it's difficult to differentiate stationary vs dynamic objects with typical background subtraction techniques. With optical flow objects at the same distance from the camera should be moving with the same direction and magnitude. You can detect moving objects because they have different velocities relative to the area around them. This isn't trivial though; be ready to do a lot of tweaking to get the detection to work well.

Comment: i have tried with optical flow but it is very slow method and also movement of  object  have opposite direction and magnitude

Comment: now i am trying with feature matching ,features of moving objects are detecting but it also detecting unwanted features like mountain, tree leaves etc, can you please tell me how to remove that unwanted features and extract wanted features. I am using ORB